# How does DI choose among multiple sources within ASP.NET Core 1

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection

In ASP.NET Core 1, some additional services were added within ConfigureServices() using AddScoped().

One of the added services is "MyUserManager" which inherits from the built-in UserManager.

A debug stack trace is showing that the default UserClaimsPrincipalFactory is using the default UserManager instead of MyUserManager.  Looking at the contructor for UserClaimsPrincipalFactory:

```
public UserClaimsPrincipalFactory(
    UserManager<TUser> userManager, 
    RoleManager<TRole> roleManager, 
    IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor)
```

I'm assuming that dependency injection is being used to create this factory.  There should be two types that would be compatible for first argument, MyUserManager or the built-in.

Is there a way to ensure choosing MyUserManager or would I need to provide a custom UserClaimsPrincipalFactory?

How in general does DI choose when there are multiple matching services that fit an argument?

**Update 2/26/2016:**

I tried removing the default user manager:

```
ServiceDescriptor defaultUserManager = services
    .Single(s => s.ServiceType.FullName.StartsWith("Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager"));

services.Remove(defaultUserManager);
```

before adding mine

```
services.AddScoped(typeof(MyUserManager<MyAppUser>))
```

Those lines run fine but then later it throws:

Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in mscorlib.dll

> Additional information: Unable to resolve service for type
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager`1[MyAppUser]' while attempting
>   to activate
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserClaimsPrincipalFactory`2[MyAppUser,
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityRole]'.

So it looks as though compatibility through inheritance is not recognized by the DI engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DI selects the last registered implementation of service.

I think the problem that you are registering your implementation type without specifying expected service type. The AddScoped call should be changed to something like that:

```
services.AddScoped(typeof(UserManager<>), typeof(MyUserManager<>));
```

Comment: Yes.  I had to add it twice though else the AccountController would also fail to resolve.   services.AddScoped<UserManager<MyAppUser>, MyUserManager<MyAppUser>>()    .AddScoped<MyUserManager<MyAppUser>>()

Answer (score 0):

I Believe you need to use the .AddTransient Function or use a ContainerBuilder in the ConfigureServices function as per the following document: [Asp.net 5 dependency injection](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/dependency-injection.html)